# Write elastic search filter search using ES Java API v7.x

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-rest-client

I tried to write a filter query using elastic search Java API version [7.6](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html)

But there is no good documentation on how to write a filter context search.

Anyone know how to write Java API for the following:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [
        { "match": { "title":   "Search"        }},
        { "match": { "content": "Elasticsearch" }}
      ],
      "filter": [ 
        { "term":  { "status": "published" }},
        { "range": { "publish_date": { "gte": "2015-01-01" }}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
List<QueryBuilder> mustClauses = boolQueryBuilder.must();
mustClauses.add(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("title", "Search"));
mustClauses.add(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("content", "Elasticsearch"));

List<QueryBuilder> filterClauses = boolQueryBuilder.filter();
filterClauses.add(QueryBuilders.termQuery("status", "published"));
filterClauses.add(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("publish_date").gte("2015-01-01"));


SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

System.out.println(searchRequest.toString());
```

The resulting query is

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "Search",
              "operator": "OR",
              "prefix_length": 0,
              "max_expansions": 50,
              "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
              "lenient": false,
              "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
              "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
              "boost": 1.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "content": {
              "query": "Elasticsearch",
              "operator": "OR",
              "prefix_length": 0,
              "max_expansions": 50,
              "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
              "lenient": false,
              "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
              "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
              "boost": 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "status": {
              "value": "published",
              "boost": 1.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "publish_date": {
              "from": "2015-01-01",
              "to": null,
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true,
              "boost": 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please show me how to execute this query using the client?

Comment: I found how to execute it. Can you help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61275532/why-this-elasticsearch-query-doesnt-return-anything