# Why this elasticsearch query doesnt return anything

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I performed below `elasticsearch` query.

```
GET amasyn/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "filter" : {
                "term": {"ordernumber": "112-9550919-9141020"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not get any hits

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

But I have a document having this `ordernumber` in the index.
`ordernumber` is a text field.

When I change the above query by replacing `term` with `match`, I get total number of hits as the no of hits for the given query.
Please explain what's happening here and how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because since you used `ordernumber` field with type as text, so it is getting analyzed. Please refer difference between text and keyword through this answer [Difference between keyword and text in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845088/difference-between-keyword-and-text-in-elasticsearch/52845279#52845279).

In this way you can define both text and keyword for your `ordernumber` field.

### Mapping

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "ordernumber": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can use term query as below :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "filter" : {
                "term": {"ordernumber.keyword": "112-9550919-9141020"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please see, how `text` and `keyword` fields are tokenized for your text.

### Standard analyzer

This analyzer is used when you were defining your field as `text`.

```
{
    "analyzer": "standard",
    "text" : "112-9550919-9141020"
}
```

### result :

```
 {
        "tokens": [
            {
                "token": "112",
                "start_offset": 0,
                "end_offset": 3,
                "type": "<NUM>",
                "position": 0
            },
            {
                "token": "9550919",
                "start_offset": 4,
                "end_offset": 11,
                "type": "<NUM>",
                "position": 1
            },
            {
                "token": "9141020",
                "start_offset": 12,
                "end_offset": 19,
                "type": "<NUM>",
                "position": 2
            }
        ]
    }
```

### Keyword Analyzer

This analyzer is used when you are defining your field as `keyword`.

```
{
    "analyzer": "keyword",
    "text" : "112-9550919-9141020"
}
```

### Result

```
 {
        "tokens": [
            {
                "token": "112-9550919-9141020",
                "start_offset": 0,
                "end_offset": 19,
                "type": "word",
                "position": 0
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Can you send me the curl command to create the mapping? I can make it as a `PUT`